# How do you get an object from a database without knowing the model in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm writing a migration (not in the practical sense) from an older version of my sqlite database to a newer one using Entity Framework Core, EFcore.

I have a database with a row in a table I'd like to get. I would like to use EFcore in order to get an object representing the data in that table if it exists. I know what the old implementation looks like, so I can parse the object just fine. I just need to know how or if it's possible to use EFcore to do this.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Raw sql, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah but it seems you can only execute raw sql, `FromSql()`, from a known model..

Comment: You can also use plain ADO.NET https://elanderson.net/2016/04/execute-raw-sql-in-entity-framework-core/

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Best way to find out if EF Core is able to do what you want is read the documentation. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/basic

Comment: I'm very confused. Why would you not be able to do it? If you have EF implemented then the returned type will be the data in the table. For example a class with properties corresponding to the data. Something is not clear here :/

Comment: The problem is I have a table in an old database and don't want to write a model for it, I just want to get the raw data from the old database using EF. Hope that helps. Thanks.